# Bitflag enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums, type-systems, bitflags

Using enums for storing bitflags in C++ is a bit troublesome, since once the enum values are ORed they loose their enum-type, which causes errors without explicit casting.

The accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199606/how-should-c-bitflag-enumerations-be-translated-into-c) suggests overloading the `|` operator:

```
FlagsSet operator|(FlagsSet a, FlagsSet b) 
{ 
    return FlagsSet(int(a) | int(b)); 
}
```

I'd like to know if this method has any runtime implications?

Comment: +1 Because I didn't know this technique yet.

Comment: switch `int` to `unsigned` - otherwise you're asking for other code to end up with sign-extension issues (bit flags are never signed!  that would be insanely foolish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Runtime implications in terms of correctness?  No - this should be exactly what you want.

Runtime implications in terms of speed?  I would expect any decent compiler to optimize this away properly to the minimal number of instructions for a release build (although you might want to add `inline` just to be sure).

Comment: +1. Regarding `inline`: smart compilers will ignore the keyword and inline code at their discretion; it is generally useless to mark functions inline for performance reasons these days. There is, however, very much different reason to add `inline`, assuming the function is defined in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

It potentially does three copies and a function call, barring RVO, registers, and/or inlining optimizations.

Naked bitwise OR operations themselves usually decompose to a single processor instruction.

Comment: Not only is that *probably* not a bottleneck, but you admit yourself the compiler could be smart enough to optimize this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.

The code will be the same speed as without type casts.

But whether the code is fast is irrelevant, because a type named 'FlagSet' will most probably be used in a context of conditionals test (-> "if (Flag)"), which is more of a hit to speed than a bit wise 'or' of two values of the size of a register.

Answer (score 0):

use std::bitset for your bit flags... much simpler ;)
or boost::dynamic_bitset.

Comment: this doesn't accomplish bit-flag usage semantics or reduce the overhead one bit!  a bitset is the moral equivalent of `vector<bool>` which is nothing like a set of bit-flags.

Comment: much shame :(  - sorry, my own ignorance - bitset does indeed have bitwise operations, is not vector<bool> - I am an idiot. :(